# WebView not getting rendered on Application launch in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I create WebView in xamarin, it is not visible when the application is launched. It gets visible when the view is readjusted.
How can I resolve the above issue.

Here is sample code that I am using

```
 var browser = new WebView();
 var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource ();

public SamplePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout
    {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        Children = 
        {
           sometextbox,
           browser 
        }
    }
}

//Code within some button's event
htmlSource.Html = @"<html><body>
        <h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>
        <p>Welcome to WebView.</p>
        </body></html>";
    browser.Source = htmlSource;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the FillAndExpand should be on the webview, not on the StackLayout

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `WebView` has no idea how big it needs to be and so it is probably there but has no size. What I do is to assign a `Width` and `Height` in `SizeChanged` like so:

```
public SamplePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout
    {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        Children = 
        {
           sometextbox,
           browser 
        }
    }

    SizeChanged += (sender, args) => {
        browser.WidthRequest = Width;
        browser.HeightRequest = Height * 0.75;
    }
}
```

If the browser still does not show up, keep the `SizeChanged()` code since it will update the `WebView` on rotation but also add the same code to `OnAppearing()`:

```
protected override void OnAppearing() {
    base.OnAppearing();

    browser.WidthRequest  = Width;
    browser.HeightRequest = Height * 0.75;
}
```

If you needed to do that upon button click you could do that or you could even leave the above code in place and just change `WebView.IsVisible`.